# Display images with multiple columns and rows (nxn) has memory issue in Android

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollview, universal-image-loader

I am showing properties list in scroll view has nxn matrix view. This has load issue (memory out and taking more time to load). To fix this issue I have tried few solutions but couldn't attain 100%.

1. I changed column scroll view to listview and tried but the result shows last column values in all listview's. I knew the problem is the adapter datasetchange will affect all view how to overcome this issue ?
2. And the most valuable solution is to load images in scrollview with those are visible in the screen and on change of visible (Scrolling) we can load the images. How to attain this?

I tried with background process (doinbackground) for image load as well.

Comment: Check out GridView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html. It load images when needed.

Comment: I thought to use gridview but the problem was i want to scroll every single column not the entire view.